# Rails - find the team with the most superheroes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find the team with the most superheroes. I did some googling, but still cannot figure out what to do as I think there is a lot of SQL involved. Basically, I want the view file to display: "The team with the most superheroes is [team name] and the number of superheroes in this team is [number]." Your help would much be appreciated as I am only a beginner in Rails.

This is the best I could come up with in my view file:

```
<% current_user.teams.each do |team| %>
  <%= team.superheroes.count%> 
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :superheroes
  has_many :teams, through: :superheroes
end
```

superhero.rb

```
class Superhero < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :superhero_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :superhero_teams
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :superhero_teams
  has_many :superheroes, through: :superhero_teams
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Superhero.joins(:teams).group('superheros.id').order("count(superheros.id) DESC")
```

It will arrange the no of superhero in each team, with the largest count at top.
So the first record of the query will be the answer you are looking for.

You Can also re-check the result by looking at the counts

```
Superhero.joins(:teams).group('superheros.id').order("count(superheros.id) DESC").count("superheros.id")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teams = Team.left_joins(:superheroes)
    .group(:id) # group by superhero id
    .select(
       # teams.*
       Teams.arel_table[Arel.star], 
       # COUNT(superheroes.*) AS superheroes_count
       Superhero.arel_table[Arel.star].count.as('superheroes_count')
     )
     .order(superheroes_count: :desc)

teams.each do |team|
  puts "#{team.name} has #{team.superheroes_count} members"
end
```

This selects a count of the number of joined rows and orders the results by it. An alternative is to add a [counter-cache to the association](https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-start-using-counter-caches-in-rails) which makes for more effective read queries at the price of an extra UPDATE query when creating the records.